# How to count number of rows in multiple tables

Tags: mysql

I have two different tables with Men's and Women's rankings.

```
id | rank | name | surname | totalpoints | lvpoints | itf points
1  | 1    | Nick | Fisher  | 100         | 50       | 50
```

Structure of tables is the same.
For example, mens table contains 70 rows and womens 52.

My code for getting COUNT of mens table:

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM mensranking";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$count = $row['count'];
echo $count;
?>
```

My goal is to get number 122 (count of mens table + count of womens table).

Tried many options (what have found on stackoverflow), nothing worked for me.

Comment: Fix your data so men and women are stored together in the same table, with a column for gender.

Answer (score 0):

Below is your solution. But I will recommend you to make single table with gender distribution like new filed that indicate user is male/female then you dont need to use union all to count both table records. One more thing you can use distinct based on your data requirements.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM
(
    select distinct id from mensranking

    union all

    select distinct id from womensranking
) total_records
```

Comment: It would be more efficient to get the count from the two tables and then combiine those, than creating an intermediate (derived) table of the individual rows. If we want count of just distinct id values,  `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id) AS cnt FROM ...`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd write one query, like this:

```
 SELECT SUM(t.cnt) AS `count`
   FROM ( SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM womensranking
          UNION ALL
          SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM mensranking
        ) t
```

There are many alternatives, but this approach is a *single* query, one round trip to the database.

If we need to get the individual counts from each table, then I'd do it like this:

```
  SELECT 'womensranking' AS tbl, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM womensranking
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'mensranking', COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM mensranking
```

Then fetch both rows. Again, that's just one roundtrip to the database to get both rows (both counts).